# Looping through all documents in a site through powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I'm new to powershell and trying to loop through all document libraries of a site and find/output those file locations into a CSV which have a custom column value equals Null.

Any link or sample code would be very helpful.

Please note we are using Sharepoint 2016 on-premise.

Answer (score 0):

One sample to start with:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$webs = (Get-SPSite "<SiteURL>" | Get-SPWeb -Limit all -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
$Lists = $webs.Lists
$ListItemCollection = @()

Foreach($List in $Lists) {
    if($List.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"){
        $list.Items | Where-Object { $_["<ColumnInternalName>"] -eq Null} | foreach {
            $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
            $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "URL" -value $_.URL
            $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Name" -value $_["Name"]
     
            #Add the object with property to an Array
            $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
        }
    }
}
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\LibData.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

References:

[Export SharePoint List Items to CSV using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html)

[Get items from SharePoint List using PowerShell script.](https://www.robertkuzma.com/2012/09/get-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-powershell-script/)